# Excel cell showing value from formula while still allowing manual entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a column of cells populated through a VLOOKUP. However, I've now been asked to make those cells allow for a manual override, while still showing the VLOOKUP value if there's no override.

Unfortunately there's a requirement to have the override entered in the same cell - otherwise I'd just add a couple of helper columns and it'd be trivial.

Is there another way to let a cell show a formula-based value, accept an override and restore the formula if there's no manual value?

Comment: Not without vba.  Once a formula is overridden it is gone and must be put back either through vba or manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual practice is to use an extra cell.  For example, put the `Vlookup()` formula in cell **B1** and the override value in cell **C1**,

Then in **A1** enter:

=IF(C1="",B1,C1)

This allows **A1** to display either the `Vlookup()` or the override *(if it has been entered)*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there'd no way to make it automatically restore the formula; you have to do it using VBA; I recommend a Command Button with a script that resets the cell.

If you want to have minimal reliance on VBA, and not lose the formula, you could set it so that the result is actually calculated in a cell hidden elsewhere, and the cell that the user inputs to just points there automatically.